# Customize Pre-Chat Form on Salesforce-

Tags: pre-chat

Rename Label without chancing them globally on pre chat form. Case Subject, we 'd like  rename Subject field as a How can I help you.Is it possible to achieve this without coding. If we need to modify code what is the sample codes you suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.You can change the "subject" label using the out-of-the-box offered functionality of "Rename Tabs & labels" as explained in [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.snapins_chat_customize_prechat_form.htm&type=5)

Click path: Setup> Quick Find> Rename Tabs & labels> Search for "cases" and click edit> In step 2, change the label of Subject to "How can I help you"

Note that this change will reflect everywhere in your org too(Like list views, etc)

2.Optionally, select a custom Lightning Component to replace the standard component.

Click path: Setup> Quick Find>Embedded Service Deployments>View>cick Edit on Chat Settings> You can see that prechat form can be customized with Lightning Components

More about custom components for pre-chat on [Lightning Web Components for Embedded Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_lightning_web_components.htm) and [Base Prechat LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightningsnapin-base-prechat/documentation)